# Trying to get formula correct

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Excel sheet:

[image: Sheet]

As you see in above image im trying to get word "Explain" in column H using if formula.

```
=IF(J2="Same as last quarter","Explain",IF(K2="New Balance","Explain",IF(L2="Balance Rolled Off","Explain")))
```

I'm currently using the above formula, but it does not let me add column M in same formula. How can I add it?

Comment: Where are you putting this formula? Where do you want to add column H in that formula, for what purpose?

Comment: I am putting that formula in column H..I wanna add column M in that formula same as Column j, K, L which I have done it. thank you. Sorry, for confusion.

Comment: You can Nest 7 IFs in Excel formula I guess. Just include one more Else in the innermost IF to evaluate for M.

Comment: @Nikhil, do you want **Explain** in Col H when in ALL 4 cells contains the said values or in any of the Cells?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the output is the same use OR:

```
=IF(OR(J2="Same as last quarter",K2="New Balance",L2="Balance Rolled Off",M2 = "variance greater than threshold, % Greater than threshold"),"Explain","")
```